# What are the design consideration for adding unit testing project to a legacy ASP.net MVC 3 project

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, unit-testing, resharper

I have a project in Asp.net MVC 3. There is no unit test project associated with it at present. I would like to add unit test project for this MVC applicaton. In my understanding, one of the pre-requisite for having effective unit test project for an MVC application is to have the project with dependencies injected in the controller and or business class methods etc.

1) What are all those design considerations for getting an effective unit testing result?

2) I understand Resharper provides some kind of assistance in generating unit testable code? How to do this using Resharper?

Thanks much!